# What purpose does「お願いだ」serve?

Tags: word-choice

I am pretty sure I have heard people saying お願い before making a request. For example:

お願いだ、部屋を綺麗にしてください。

The second sentence translates to "**Please** clean your room". So the question is, what is the purpose of the お願いだ? Translating it literally would make "Please, Please clean your room"

By the above convention, if I were to say お願いだ、部屋を綺麗にして (no ください), will the sentence also mean "Please clean your room"?

Comment: As an aside, お願い**だ** is non-polite form, so you can't mix it with ください.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here お願いだ is an intensifier that stresses the meaning being conveyed. The literal meaning is something along the lines of "This is my wish." Of course it is often translated as "please" in accordance with English speaking customs. Here as you have noted it presents a bit of an awkward translation issue with ください in the same sentence.

I would understand or translate it as something like this:

> Clean your room please. I am serious.
>
> Please clean your room. For real.

Or more loosely:

> Would you mind getting your room cleaned up?

It is used in other similar situations where you can safely translate it as "please".

> 待ってくれ、お願いだ。
> Wait a sec, please!

Comment: Pretty well on the mark.  It often gets translated as "I'm begging you!" followed by the request.